# Makefile percent sign in rule not being recognised

Tags: makefile

I just began learning about GNU make yesterday. As the title says, it appears that the % sign in my Makefile is not being recognised. Or perhaps I am using it the wrong way. Can someone enlighten me?

```
CXX = clang++
EXE = Invaders

SDL = -F./lib
LDFLAGS = $(SDL)

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj

SRC = $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/util/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/misc/*.cpp)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o bin/$@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.h
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<
```

Console output:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/main.o', needed by `Invaders'.  Stop.
```

[Tree view of my entire project with directories /obj and /src expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MDKm.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.h
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<
```

does not fit `obj/main.o`, because there is no `src/main.h`.

(Also, please put the necessary information in the body of the question, don't rely on a link to an image.)